# VS Code - keyboard binding for Clojure only

Tags: visual-studio-code

My keybindings.json file looks like this in part

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+f5",
    "command": "clojureVSCode.evalAndShowResult",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == clojure"
}
```

The binding does work fine, the problem is that the key binding is linked in files other than just Clojure (ie JavaScript, TypeScript, etc).

What's the correct way to tell Code to only associate this key binding for Clojure files?